# What does "A dime on the vig" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

In *Donnie Brasco* (1997), Sonny Black speaks to electrolarynx Man, who try to
sell Sergio Valentes:

> Sonny Black: I got a guy that's in the middle of this load of  Sergio
> Valentes.
>
> Man: **A dime on the vig**.
>
> Sonny Black: So, what do you got on the street?
>
> Man: $100,000.
>
> (*Sonny Black returns pants back*)
>
> Sonny Black: That should be $250,000 by the end of the year.

Actually dime is coin that has 10 cent worth of value in the U.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the more common slang usage of dime to mean 10 cents, it seems that in some gambling circles a dime is also a $1000.

A vig, or vigorish, is the "tax" taken by a bookie on a straight bet. Say you bet $100 - if the vig is 10% you'd have to stump $110.

https://sportsbookwire.usatoday.com/wager-101-sports-betting-terms-and-definitions/

However, it appears that "dime on the vig" can also mean that the vig is 10%

https://www.docsports.com/how-to-what-is-does/dime-line-mean-sports-betting-wagering.html

I'm not sure exactly where this fits in the context of selling jeans - possibly that the man will buy the jeans at 10% of the retail price, or take 10% of the money in the deal, or simply loan the money at 10%.

Comment: I thought the vig was also the interest on a loan. So a dime on the vig might be 10% interest.